# How to flatten and remove duplicates from a list of lists of datetime64 using numpy or pandas or Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, vectorization

In Python, I have a list of lists of pandas timestamps, e.g. consider the following typing hint `input: list[list[pd.Timestamp]]`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Example list of lists of Pandas Timestamps
input = [[pd.Timestamp('2023-09-01 10:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2023-09-01 11:00:00')],
        [pd.Timestamp('2023-09-02 12:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2023-09-02 13:00:00')],
        [pd.Timestamp('2023-09-03 14:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2023-09-03 15:00:00')]]
```

This input represents a list of datetime ranges.
For the sake of debugging and simplicity I prefer to view this information as a dataframe:

```
input_df = pd.DataFrame(input, columns=[['left', 'right']])
```

Now I need to:

1. Flatten the input
2. Remove duplicates
3. Apply the same string format (in a vectorized manner, e.g. `strftime("%Y/%m/%d/%H")` on all elements)

Now, should I do this in pandas, numpy (since all elements are of the same type), or in Python?
What is the fastest and more elegant way?

Comment: How looks expected ouput from sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need get all hours between left and right columns (if difference should be 2 or more hours) use:

```
#remove nested list in columns names for avoid MultiIndex
input_df = pd.DataFrame(input, columns=['left', 'right'])

#substract columns and convert to hours difference
repeat = input_df['right'].sub(input_df['left']).dt.total_seconds().div(3600).add(1)

#repeat left column
s = input_df.loc[input_df.index.repeat(repeat), 'left']

#add counter by hours, remove dupes and convert to custom format
out = (s.add(pd.to_timedelta(s.groupby(s).cumcount(), unit='H')).drop_duplicates()
               .dt.strftime("%Y/%m/%d/%H").tolist())

print (out)
['2023/09/01/10', '2023/09/01/11', '2023/09/02/12',
 '2023/09/02/13', '2023/09/03/14', '2023/09/03/15']
```

If difference is not important and need only flatten values use numpy:

```
input_df = pd.DataFrame(input, columns=['left', 'right'])

out = pd.Series(np.unique(np.ravel(input_df[['left','right']]))).dt.strftime("%Y/%m/%d/%H").tolist()
print (out)
['2023/09/01/10', '2023/09/01/11', '2023/09/02/12', 
 '2023/09/02/13', '2023/09/03/14', '2023/09/03/15']
```

Comment: Is there a vectorized strftime in Python/numpy so I can skip the conversion to dataframe at the start and to series at the end?

Comment: @LucaM - Yop, then use `out = pd.Series(np.unique(np.ravel(input))).dt.strftime("%Y/%m/%d/%H").tolist()`

Comment: @LucaM - Or `out = [x.strftime("%Y/%m/%d/%H") for x in np.unique(np.ravel(input))]`

Comment: Using pd.Series needs pandas so that does not answer my comment, instead using a list comphresion does not run elements in parallel I guess. I was wondering if there was a way to vectorize the striftime conversion in parallel somehow. I guess I should need pandas, is that right?

Comment: @LucaM yes, if need vectorized strftime need panda.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result efficiently using pandas as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
    
# Example list of lists of Pandas Timestamps
input_data = [
    [pd.Timestamp('2023-09-01 10:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2023-09-01 11:00:00')],
    [pd.Timestamp('2023-09-02 12:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2023-09-02 13:00:00')],
    [pd.Timestamp('2023-09-03 14:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2023-09-03 15:00:00')]
]

# Create a DataFrame
input_df = pd.DataFrame(input_data, columns=['left', 'right'])

# Step 1: Flatten the input
flattened_df = input_df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)

# Step 2: Remove duplicates
unique_df = flattened_df.drop_duplicates()

# Step 3: Apply the same string format
unique_df['formatted'] = unique_df['right'].dt.strftime("%Y/%m/%d/%H")

# Resulting DataFrame with flattened, unique, and formatted timestamps
print(unique_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
    
# Example list of lists of Pandas Timestamps
input_data = [
    [pd.Timestamp('2023-09-01 10:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2023-09-01 11:00:00')],
    [pd.Timestamp('2023-09-02 12:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2023-09-02 13:00:00')],
    [pd.Timestamp('2023-09-03 14:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2023-09-03 15:00:00')]
]

# Create a DataFrame
input_df = pd.DataFrame(input_data, columns=['left', 'right'])

# Step 1: Flatten the input
flattened_df = input_df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)

# Step 2: Remove duplicates
unique_df = flattened_df.drop_duplicates()

# Step 3: Apply the same string format
unique_df['formatted'] = unique_df['right'].dt.strftime("%Y/%m/%d/%H")

# Resulting DataFrame with flattened, unique, and formatted timestamps
print(unique_df)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).